# Substitute item in numpy array with list

Tags: python, arrays, python-2.7, numpy

I want to replace an item in a numpy array composed of 0 and 1.
I want to replace 1 with the list [0,1] and the 0 with the list [1,0].

I found the function `numpy.where()`, but it doesn't work with lists.
Is there a function or something similar to do the equivalent for `numpy.where(vector==1,[0,1], [1,0])` ?

Comment: I get the feeling you're trying to create a one-hot tensor.  Is that the purpose?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can actually use `where` for that if you wish:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> vector = np.random.randint(0, 2, (8, 8))
>>> vector
array([[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1],
       [1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0],
       [1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
       [1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0],
       [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0]])
>>> np.where(vector[..., None] == 1, [0,1], [1,0])
# btw. if vector has only 0 and 1 entries you can leave out the " == 1 "
array([[[0, 1],
        [1, 0],
        [1, 0],
        [1, 0],
        [1, 0],
        [1, 0],
        [0, 1],
        [0, 1]],

       [[0, 1],
        [0, 1],
        [1, 0],
        [0, 1],
        [1, 0],
        [1, 0],
        [1, 0],

        etc.
```

Answer (score 2):

Simple indexing should do the job:

```
In [156]: x = np.array([0,1,0,0,1,1,0])
In [157]: y = np.array([[1,0],[0,1]])
In [158]: y[x]
Out[158]: 
array([[1, 0],
       [0, 1],
       [1, 0],
       [1, 0],
       [0, 1],
       [0, 1],
       [1, 0]])
```

And just to be sure this is a general solution, not some 'boolean' fluke

```
In [162]: x = np.array([0,1,0,0,1,2,2])
In [163]: y = np.array([[1,0],[0,1],[1,1]])
In [164]: y[x]
Out[164]: 
array([[1, 0],
       [0, 1],
       [1, 0],
       [1, 0],
       [0, 1],
       [1, 1],
       [1, 1]])
```

Comment: This is the answer the OP is looking for, not the one s/he accepted. Anyway, very neat!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you want to make [one-hot vector encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-hot):

```
a = np.array([1, 0, 1, 1, 0])  # initial array
b = np.zeros((len(a), 2))  # where 2 is number of classes
b[np.arange(len(a)), a] = 1
print(b)
```

result:

```
array([[ 0.,  1.],
       [ 1.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  1.],
       [ 0.,  1.],
       [ 1.,  0.]])
```

Comment: It's a coincidence. I have a lot of elements in my array. Ist here a way to make it less "expensive"?

Comment: anyway you will need to create auxiliary array to store result because numpy does not allow dynamically change dimensions for specific items. So my solution must work for your problem (in case of 1-rank input array)

Answer (score 0):

Since it's not possible to *grow* the array dynamically in NumPy, you've to convert the array to list, do the substitution as desired, and then convert the result back to NumPy array like:

```
In [21]: vector = np.array([0, 0, 1, 0, 1])

In [22]: vlist = vector.tolist()

In [23]: vlist
Out[23]: [0, 0, 1, 0, 1]

In [24]: new_list = [[1, 0] if el == 0 else [0, 1] for idx, el in enumerate(vlist)]

In [25]: result = np.array(new_list)

In [26]: result
Out[26]: 
array([[1, 0],
       [1, 0],
       [0, 1],
       [1, 0],
       [0, 1]])
```

If your 1D array is not that large enough, then list comprehension is not that bad of an approach.

Answer (score 0):

hpaulj's answer would be the ideal way of doing this. An alternative is to reshape your original numpy array, and apply your standard `np.where()` operation.

```
import numpy as np

x = np.array([0,1,0,0,1,1,0])
x = np.reshape(x,(len(x),1))
# Equivalently, if you want to be explicit:
# x = np.array([[e] for e in x])
print np.where(x==1,[1,0],[0,1])
# Result:
array([[0, 1],
       [1, 0],
       [0, 1],
       [0, 1],
       [1, 0],
       [1, 0],
       [0, 1]])
```